# Пунктуация. Пушкинский Онегин

Tags: пунктуация

Решаю сборник и вижу замечательную цитату из критиков русской литературы: «Пушкинский Онегин является в романе человеком, которого убили воспитание и светская жизнь, которому всё пригляделось, всё приелось, всё прилюбилось (1) и вся жизнь которого состояла в том, "что он зевал средь модных и старинных зал"».

Вопрос. Если в остальных случаях понятно, почему стоит запятая, то почему в случае (1) запятой нет? Разве *жизнь состояла в том* — не полноценное самостоятельное предложение? Или — *он зевал средь зал?*

Кто-нибудь может разъяснить простым языком? Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> почему в случае (1) запятой нет?

Потому что союз "и" в данном предложении соединяет **однородные придаточные:**

***Пушкинский Онегин является в романе человеком,***

(каким?) ***которого убили воспитание...***

***и***

(каким?) ***вся жизнь которого...***

[**См.:**](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=134#pp134)

> **§ 119.** В сложноподчиненных предложениях с несколькими однородными придаточными знаки препинания ставятся по правилам, действующим при
>   отделении однородных членов простого предложения...
>
> 2. Между двумя придаточными, соединенными одиночными соединительными или разделительными союзами ***и, или, либо, да*** (в значении «и»), запятая не ставится (при этом подчинительный союз или союзное
>      слово может и не повторяться):
>
> *Подходя к дому, я вспомнил, что неподалеку в еловом перелеске с можжевельником не раз спугивал старого петуха-черныша **и** еще там
>   жила матка с одним молодым петушком.*

Answer (score 1):

Сложное предложение с тремя однородными придаточными: 
[Пушкинский Онегин является в романе человеком], (которого убили воспитание и светская жизнь), (которому всё пригляделось, всё приелось, всё прилюбилось) и (вся жизнь которого состояла в том), "что он зевал средь модных и старинных зал". Постановка знаков препинания как при однородных членах предложения, соединенных одиночным союзом и. Запятая не нужна. Схема О, О и О.